# Divide by Zero Warning in LU Decomposition- Doolittle Algorithm working

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have implemented the standard equations/algorithm of LU Decomposition of a Matrix by following this link: ([1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doolittle-algorithm-lu-decomposition/)) and ([2](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-algorithm-for-doolittle-s-method-for-lu-decompositions))
This returns the LU decomposition of a square matrix like below perfectly. 
My problem is, however- it also gives a `Divide by Zero warning`.

Code here:

```
import numpy as np

def LUDecomposition (A):
    L = np.zeros(np.shape(A),np.float64)
    U = np.zeros(np.shape(A),np.float64)
    acc = 0
    L[0,0]=1
    for i in np.arange(len(A)):

        for k in range(i,len(A)):

            for j in range(0,i):
                acc += L[i,j]*U[j,k]
            U[i,k] = A[i,k]-acc


            for m in range(k+1,len(A)):
                if m==k:
                    L[m,k]=1
                else:

                    L[m,k] = (A[m,k]-acc)/U[k,k]
            acc=0
    return (L,U)

A = np.array([[-4, -1, -2],
              [-4, 12,  3],
              [-4, -2, 18]])

L, U = LUDecomposition (A)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Firstly, please don't post pictures like that, it means people have to type out your example code by hand and it isn't compatible with screen readers, etc.  Secondly, if you paste your code into a file and run it as a normal python script (ie not in jupyter) it will tell you exactly where the problem is.  Unsurprisingly, it happens on the only line with a `/` on it.  If you use a debugger, you can set a breakpoint on that line and examine why it is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you may have made some indentation errors regarding the first inner level `for` loops: `U` must be evaluated before `L` ; you also didn't correctly compute the summation term `acc` and didn't properly set the diagonal terms of `L` to 1. Following some other syntax modifications, you may rewrite your function as follows:

```
def LUDecomposition(A):

    n = A.shape[0]
    L = np.zeros((n,n), np.float64)
    U = np.zeros((n,n), np.float64)

    for i in range(n):
        # U
        for k in range(i,n):
            s1 = 0  # summation of L(i, j)*U(j, k) 
            for j in range(i):
                s1 += L[i,j]*U[j,k]
            U[i,k] = A[i,k] - s1

        # L
        for k in range(i,n):
            if i==k:
                # diagonal terms of L 
                L[i,i] = 1
            else:
                s2 = 0 # summation of L(k, j)*U(j, i) 
                for j in range(i):
                    s2 += L[k,j]*U[j,i]
                L[k,i] = (A[k,i] - s2)/U[i,i]

    return L, U
```

which gives this time the correct output for matrix `A` when compared to [scipy.linalg.lu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html) as a reliable reference:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu

A = np.array([[-4, -1, -2],
              [-4, 12,  3],
              [-4, -2, 18]])

L, U = LUDecomposition(A)
P, L_sp, U_sp = lu(A, permute_l=False)

P
>>> [[1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.]])

L
>>> [[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 1.          1.          0.        ]
     [ 1.         -0.07692308  1.        ]]

np.allclose(L_sp, L))
>>>  True

U
>>> [[-4.         -1.         -2.        ]
     [ 0.         13.          5.        ]
     [ 0.          0.         20.38461538]]

np.allclose(U_sp, U))
>>>  True
```

**Note**: unlike scipy lapack getrf algorithm, this Doolittle implementation does not include pivoting, these two comparisons are then only true if permutation matrix `P` returned by `scipy.linalg.lu` is an identity matrix, *i.e.* scipy didn't performed any permutations, which is indeed the case for your matrix `A`. The permutation matrix determined in scipy algorithm is meant to optimize conditions numbers of resulting matrix in order to reduce roundoff errors. At last, you may just simply verify that `A = LU` which will always be the case if the factorization is done right:

```
A = np.random.rand(10,10)
L, U = LUDecomposition(A)

np.allclose(A, np.dot(L, U))
>>>  True
```

Nevertheless, in terms of numerical efficiency and accuracy, I wouldn't recommend you to use your own function to compute LU decomposition. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, it was a problem with my "innovation". I thought the two loops of range(i,n) is doing the same thing, so why not to combine it. Also it's evident I coded the L(i,j) wrongly